# useState not updating state object after fetching data from API endpoint

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Just starting to learn React. I wrote a simple web server that serves data from a /users endpoint. I am fetching that data in useState hook of a component, but the state object does not seem to be updating. Anyone that can point me in the right direction to get the response object data to render in the ordered list would be greatly appreciated.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const UserList = () => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {

        fetch("http://localhost:8080/users",
            {
                method: "GET"            
            }
        )
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            setUsers(res.data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
        
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>User List</h1>
            <ol>
            {
                users.forEach(u => {
                    <li>{u}</li>
                })
            }
            </ol>
        </div>
    )
}

export default UserList;
```

Comment: @DrewReese I am logging the state object in a finally block after the .catch, I just removed that to avoid cluttering up the question

Comment: There looks no error in your code. Could you see network tab in browser to check if you are actually getting response or not?

Comment: @VipulTyagi The response is being returned as expected, verified in the network tab

Comment: React states are asynchronous, so console logging *right* after enqueueing a state update will only ever log the state from the *current* render cycle, not what it will be for the *next* render cycle. Answered below with what your issue was though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are using `Array.prototype.forEach` to try and render your state. `.forEach` is a void return, however, so nothing is returned to be rendered.

## Solution

Use `Array.prototype.map` to map the `users` state to JSX.

```
{
  users.map((u, index) => (
    <li key={index}>{u}</li>
  ))
}
```